# How do i load multiple dataframes into an llm as an input with prompt?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, large-language-model, llama

Problem Statement: I have some tabular data (consider as multiple pandas dataframes with different shapes and sizes, additionally schema could be entirely different for each of the dfs).
I need to generate a combined summary from all the dataframes.

I tried passing df as string but ran into max_token exceeded problem. Also tried with CSVLoader (from langchain), here i ran into max_context_token exceeded issue.

Currently I'm using gpt-4 but not limited as need to try out with various other models.

Answer (score 0):

I have never try agent pandas dataframe, but I think that it's all needed. The Pandas Dataframe agent have also the way that can work on multiple dataframe like this. [image]

You can use pandas to read data and use agent pandas to give the solution.

Here is this link https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/toolkits/pandas.